# How to write many objects in binary file and read it an especific object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

In Python, I have to develop a simple program to write and read objects in a binary file. There will be a maximum of 11 records which will be inserted, loaded or removed one by one. It's something like the file has 11 slots and when the data is inserted, the slot index will be passed. So when the user tries to insert in an index which is already populated, it fails and the user gets the message.

So, my idea was to save the data based depending on the size of the object. For example: if the user inserts a data in the index 3, i would not insert in the beggining of the file, would start inserting in "3 * (Object size)"

But the problem is that the objects sizes aren't always the same, so it would loose the reference to the data requested.

```
import pickle

class Reg:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def display(self):
        print("{}: {}".format(self.id, self.name))

user = Reg(642213, "{}{}".format("José da Silva", 642213))
print(len(pickle.dumps(user)))
user = Reg(462903, "{}{}".format("Carlos Ribeiro", 462903))
print(len(pickle.dumps(user)))
user = Reg(502453, "{}{}".format("Alberto", 502453))
print(len(pickle.dumps(user)))
user = Reg(189567, "{}{}".format("Rodrigo Peixoto Gama", 189567))
print(len(pickle.dumps(user)))
```

> The console log is: 81 81 74 87

So, how can i do it? Is there a way to set a default size for all the objects?

Comment: Objects size vary depending on the data. I don't think you can set a default size of the object if i understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

One, if you know the maximum size of the objects, you can use that as the fixed size for all of them. The object protocol shouldn't have a problem detecting the end of the object when you read too much.

The second way, is to create an "index".

The index is a collection of 11 fixed length offsets, stored at the beginning of the file.

Then when you add in the new object, you can just update the index with it's offset. This way you can also put things in "out of order" (i.e. the "3rd" item is the 3rd slot in the index, but the first object in the data).

Obviously in more complicated scenarios these both get much more nuanced.

But if your example is limited, either can do the trick.

Addenda:

On the one hand, you can pad the name out to 20 characters with spaces, and simply trim them off later. That makes them all the same size.

On the other, it doesn't really matter. You need to do random dis I/O to locate the objects. You can simply seek to the proper offset in the file and write/read from there. The pickle process will do the rest.

So, in that case, you don't need to know how big the objects are, just as long as they aren't too long.

Comment: I guess i'm going to do the first one. My class must have 3 attributes: id (integer), age(integer) and name(string with maximum of 20 char). So, based on this, i know the maximum size of the objects, but how do i set all the objects to a fixed size?